# Why tags are reordered when posting a question?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, questions, tags

I was posting a question and i added my tags like `jquery status message twitter` and in my question it was reordered like `jquery twitter message status`...

- Does reordering tags of a question make sense?
- On what basis tags or reordered?

Comment: probably order by popularity

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Tags are reordered from left to right by popularity.

Most popular on the left, least popular on the right.